# Organising equal regex matches on different lines in a dictionary

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract meta data of the occurrences of regexes. Particularly I am stuck at how to (best) extract the line of the text where a match occurs. The problem arises, when there are multiple equal matches.

Accordingly I wrote a little script extracting the desired pattern and looping it through with re.finditer. However, I am stuck on how to best "pause" my loop to return the correct match_index with the line. I feel generators may be worth a look or I might have overlooked an out-of-the-box method.

What would be the most "pythonic" (and actually working) way to do the following?

```
import re

string = """a zero line
we can write pattern_1 here
let's buffer here, just chilling, everything's ok
I think it's time for a second pattern_2
let's a do another pattern_1
ciao
"""

pattern = re.compile(r"\w{7}_\d")
found = re.finditer(pattern, string)

matches_list = []
for match_index, match in enumerate(list(found)):
    for index, line in enumerate(string.splitlines()):
        if match.group() in line:
            match_meta_dict = {
                'match_index': match_index,
                'line': index
            }
            matches_list.append(match_meta_dict)
            break

print(matches_list)
```

I would like to get a list of dictionaries where the line corresponds to the according pattern like so:

```
[{'match_index': 0, 'line': 1}, {'match_index': 1, 'line': 3}, {'match_index': 2, 'line': 4}]
```

Instead I am getting (obviously):

```
[{'match_index': 0, 'line': 1}, {'match_index': 1, 'line': 3}, {'match_index': 2, 'line': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure an array of dictionaries is the best data structure to store this? I think an array of integers would suffice, because `match_index` always starts at 0 and increases by 1, so you really just needs to store the line numbers. The index of that line number *is* the match index. If you insist on an array of dictionaries, you can easily convert the array of line numbers to that.

```
line_numbers = []
for index, line in enumerate(string.splitlines()):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
        line_numbers.append(index)
```

Converting to array of dictionary:

```
matches_list = []
for index, line_number in enumerate(line_numbers):
    matches_list.append({"match_index": index, "line": line_number})
```

Comment: Duh... I am stupid. Thank you very much! 
I agree with you that a list would normally suffice. However, I am building a set of features from many texts and the line is just one feature. Therefore I am organising everything in a list of dicts to have it easier with pandas later.

Comment: @GregK Have you considered using classes?

Comment: I am building a class at the moment, but I feel you're thinking about it differently than I do. Care to set up a chatroom?

Comment: @GregK I have absolutely no experience at all with panda, so if panda can only handle dictionaries, use dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over lines and whenever you found a match increase a counter variable.